# Why won't ossec block SSH connections when it seems to be configured correctly?

Tags: linux, firewalls, ossec

Why won't ossec block connections from another server?

I installed ossec version 2.9.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.  In the ossec.conf file I have these lines where x.x.x.x is the IP address of a second Linux server:

```
<command>
    <name>firewall-drop</name>
    <executable>firewall-drop.sh</executable>
    <expect>x.x.x.x</expect>
    <timeout_allowed>yes</timeout_allowed>
</command>

<active-response>
    <command>firewall-drop</command>
    <location>all</location>
    <rules_id>5712</rules_id> 
    <timeout>1800</timeout> 
</active-response>
```

I restarted ossec.  Running a `ps -ef | grep ossec` showed it was running.  I have a firewall rule that allows the Linux server at x.x.x.x to SSH to the Ubuntu server with ossec.  I can still SSH from the second server to the ossec server.

I changed the timeout to 20.  I made sure it took me 25 seconds to type in the password.  I can still SSH from the second server to the ossec server. I expected the above to block SSH connections.  I tried turning off the firewall, but that did not have any effect.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The timeout in the OSSEC `<active-response>` block is after what time the response will be rolled back: in other words, after 1800 seconds (or 20 seconds, when you changed it), the IP will be allowed again.

Rule 5712 in the default configuration detects SSH brute force -- try connecting a number of times.  You can also look in the file `/var/ossec/logs/alerts/alerts.log` to see when alerts are fired.

Comment: I tried connecting over 20 times with the wrong password.  That alerts.log file never got written to.  A password is still being requested.  I can log in if I insert the correct password.  What should I do?